# I want to understand how locking works in Linux

Tags: linux, apt, dpkg

So you might have noticed on typing `apt-get update` there comes an error sometimes that says

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

I know that the error can be removed by using sudo. But I am confused as to how this mechanism works. If you could help me with that, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Do you want to know about locking or about `apt-get`? If the problem is fixed by `sudo`, it is not related to locking.

Comment: The permission denied error is actually on the call to `open(2)`, rather than any locking related calls. File locking on Linux is only advisory, have a look at `flock(2)`

Comment: I want to know about locking, I know about apt-get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your example is not about locking, it is a permission error. `apt` is trying to read/write to a file (`/var/lib/apt/lists/lock`) that it does not have permission to read/write to.

Look at `chown`, file ownership, and what is a user (on the Unix system).

---

Incidentally this file is used for locking (to prevent two `apt`s accessing the apt database at the same time).

Comment: I know the problem is a permission error. As such this would become a duplicate question. My question was, how does the lock work? Going into the depth, how does Linux lock a file so that other users can't use it?

Comment: The file is not locked so that other users can't use it, the permissions are set, so that other users can't use it. Yes the file is `lock`, but no locking is going on, well not yet, not until the program can write to the file (which in this case it can't). The question confuses two concepts. You fix the error, by using `sudo`, because it allows you to read/write the file.

Comment: Oh I get it now. Thank you so much.